# Avoid Swagger ui to display double endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi-generator

I have a yaml file to generate my endpoints based on the OpenAPI principle, but when I open my swagger-ui I see:

[image]

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  ....
....
paths:
  /cities:
    get:
      tags:
        - Cities
      summary: Get all cities
      operationId: getAllCities
      responses:
        200:
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/City'
        404:
          description: Cities not found
          content: {}
```

and the swagger config look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger2Config {

    public static final String REST_PACKAGE = "package";

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(REST_PACKAGE))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

What I'm missing to remove **cities-api-controller** from swagger ui ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Swagger2Config {

    public static final String REST_PACKAGE = "package";

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(REST_PACKAGE))
                .paths(regex("/*.*"))
                .build();
    }
```

}

Comment: Hello, thank your for your answer, you mean `groupName("public-api").select()` and not `.select().groupName("public-api")`, but sadly, I see the same result as before, I don't understand why!

Comment: OK, then remove groupname. Try out with updated answer. If still not working then add apiInfo() also, like - build().apiInfo();